# Send email after new document is created from template that includes URL from new document

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some script in Sheets that sends an email after a button is pressed letting me know the sheet is newly created. However, the way I have written the script sends me a link to the template, and not the newly created sheet. I want to have the email created include the URL from the new sheet and not the template. I have the script used below (with some information changed for anonymity):

```
function sendemail()  {
MailApp.sendEmail("name@gmail.com", "New Sheet Created", 
"The link for the new sheet is 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/");
}
```

Thank you for the help, I plan to check back frequently to answer any questions. If I need to clarify anything, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might be what you are looking for:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/93305/how-to-find-url-of-the-current-sheet

```
function getSheetUrl() {
    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = SS.getActiveSheet();
    var url = '';
    url += SS.getUrl();
    url += '#gid=';
    url += ss.getSheetId(); 
    return url;
}
```